# Network card driver not installed

Tags: wireless-networking, dell-inspiron, wifi-driver

I recently installed windows 8.1 on my Dell Inspiron 14(3421) but now I can't see any wifi networks on my network list. Simply, there is no wifi now. But, I can connect to the internet via Ethernet cable. Previously I was using 32-bit Win 8 and everything was fine. I checked the device manager and found that under óther devices', 'Nework Controller' and ÚSB 2.0-CRW' have yellow exclamation mark and have no driver installed. I tried installing driver for network controller but none of them were relevant. I tried updating driver from the properties of Network Controller but windows could not find any. Please please please help me by suggesting what should I do? or what is the relevant driver for my network card?

Hardware IDs of Network Controller:

PCI\VEN_168C&DEV_0036&SUBSYS_020C1028&REV_01
PCI\VEN_168C&DEV_0036&SUBSYS_020C1028
PCI\VEN_168C&DEV_0036&CC_028000
PCI\VEN_168C&DEV_0036&CC_0280

Comment: Have you been on the Dell support/drivers download pages? http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-14-3421/drivers

Comment: @BigChris Yes, I browsed the dell drivers download page for the my laptop but couldnot figure out which wireless driver (1703, 1704, 1705) is relevant to my Network Controller. Can you please suggest me the correct one from the above hardware IDs?

Comment: @BigChris additionally, I downloaded Dell "Wireless 1704 WiFi + Bluetooth Driver" but on installation I got an error "Activate bluetooth using wireless switch" and thus couldn't continue the installation further.

Comment: I think it might be the 1705 one

Comment: @BigChris Thank you Big Chris! I've started downloading wireless 1705 driver. I'll let you know if that works or not. :)

Comment: There's some decent information here - http://dellwindowsreinstallationguide.com/driver-sets/dell-wireless-cards/#Atheros

Comment: @ScunnerDarkly thank you very much! It seems like I am on the right track for the first time on fixing my problem. From the hardware ID I found that my wireless is 1705 from Atheros. And I have started downloading Dell Wireless 1705 + BT from Dell's website but am afraid that if I get the same error Äctivate Bluetooth using wireless switch".

Comment: Thank you @BigChris ! "Dell Wireless 1705 WiFi + Bluetooth" driver from dell product support worked perfectly for me. Everything is ok now! Even my bluetooth is working perfectly now, which, otherwise wasn't working before installing Win 8.1. 
http://www.dell.com/support/home/in/en/inbsd1/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=9TR42&fileId=3289201814&osCode=WB64A&productCode=inspiron-14-3421&languageCode=EN&categoryId=NI

Comment: Thank you @ScunnerDarkly"Dell Wireless 1705 WiFi + Bluetooth" driver from dell product support worked perfectly for me. Everything is ok now! Even my bluetooth is working perfectly now, which, otherwise wasn't working before installing Win 8.1. 
http://www.dell.com/support/home/in/en/inbsd1/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=9TR42&fileId=3289201814&osCode=WB64A&productCode=inspiron-14-3421&languageCode=EN&categoryId=NI

Comment: Thank you guys once again! I cannot express in words how much happy I am feeling at the moment. :) :)

Comment: If you want to put your comment/update that the "Dell Wireless 1705 WiFi + Bluetooth" worked as an answer it'll help people in future :)

Comment: If all the specifications mentioned above match to your system then the appropriate fix for metioned issue is to download "Dell Wireless 1705 WiFi + Bluetooth" driver from dell product support. This worked perfectly for me. 
Download from: http://www.dell.com/support/home/in/en/inbsd1/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=9TR42&fileId=3289201814&osCode=WB64A&productCode=inspiron-14-3421&languageCode=EN&categoryId=NI